# Use different Solr Similarity algo for every search

Tags: solr

Is possible in Solr 1.4 to specify which similarity class to use for every search within a single index?

Let's say, I got 2 type of search (keyword and brand). For keyword search, I want to use the DefaultSimilarity class. But, for brand search, I want to use my CustomSimilarity class.

I've been modifying the schema.xml to specify a single similarity class to use. But, I came to this requirement that I have to use 2 different similarity classes.

I'll be glad to here your thoughts on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you want to change the similarity class? What's the concrete problem with the default similary? There might be other ways to achieve what you want...

Comment: Hi Mauricio, thanks for your reply.

Actually, the default similarity is quite sufficient for normal document ranking that lean much towards on relevancy. But, our requirement on ranking is quite strict in a way that we need to compromise basic scoring (i.e. removing the effect of TF) Even adding boost values to influence the ranking sometimes failed according to our required ranking.

Comment: @snickernet - so what did you end up doing finally? I have a similar requirement.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK the Similarity can only be defined at the schema/index level and can't be overriden per fieldType or per query. (see [this](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Similarity) and [this](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins#Similarity)).

However you can customize your result ordering using other methods: boosting, [function queries](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery), a [custom analyzer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#Analyzers) per field, or even sorting.

The [Solr Relevancy Cookbook](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyCookbook) wiki is a good reference.

Comment: I've been playing around with function queries (boost) for quite some time now. But, like I said, you cannot directly dictate the ranking using this but you can influence it at some point.

Comment: @snickernet: if you need to directly set the order, use sorting.

Comment: thanks for sharing your thoughts. Yeah, you're right. Maybe I should be better looking on built-in features of Solr/Lucene (i.e. sorting, boosting) rather than building more logic on my own.